# How to create bound in scipy.optimize so optimizer can't reach more than 1 in summary of vector?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a function what takes params as vector. 
I need to restrict any of the vector variables be less than 0 and vector should be summary equal to 1

I've tried to find something in goolge and scipy docs. No luck so far.

```
def portfolio_optimization(weight_vector):
    return np.sqrt(cov_table.dot(weight_vector).sum())
```

bound what I need to apply:

```
sum(weight_vector) = 1
0 < weight_vector[i] < 1
```

Comment: The sum will be a linear constraint. The bounds are passed as bounds. Both things are documented. As minimize wraps multiple solvers, using constraints will effect in scipy chosing one supporting it.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I implement it? Docs without  examples. I still don't understand how to set bounds, constraints.

Comment: You are looking at the api docs. There are also [tutorial docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first condition is a constraint (`sum(w)=1`), as for the second you can use bounds for it. Here is a small example on how to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` with a weights vector having 4 elements:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


# objective function
func   = lambda w: np.sqrt(cov_table.dot(w).sum())

# constraint: sum(weights) = 1
fconst = lambda w: 1 - sum(w)
cons   = ({'type':'eq','fun':fconst})

# initial weights
w0   = [0, 0, 0, 0]

# define bounds
b    = (0.0, 1.0) 
bnds = (b, b, b, b)

# minimize
sol  = minimize(func,
                w0,
                bounds      = bnds,
                constraints = cons)
print(sol)
```

*Don't forget to assign a value to `cov_table` for the code to work.